# Como redimensionar essa propriedade CSS?

Tags: css

[image: Preciso que fique mais curto, porém com a mesma altura que esta atualmente.]

```
#msg{
  margin:15px;
  height:auto;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 1px;
  color: #1b196df2;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px black;
}
```

Comment: `width` diminui ele!

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Answer (score 1):

Diminuir o `width` deve resolver o seu problema.

```
#msg {
  margin:15px;
  height:auto;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 1px;
  color: #1b196df2;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deixa tudo Dinâmico.
Remove a height e width e controla com o padding.

```
#msg {
  margin:15px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  color: #1b196df2;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px black;
}
```